# Custom lookup search filter how do I set

Tags: lightning-web-components, lookup, custom, search, lookup-filter

The custom lookup Set to lookup the object "User". I want to display only users whose Department in the user object is "service".

```
<c:customLookup objectAPIName="User" IconName="standard:employee_job_position" selectedId="{!item.PM_Service__c}" Name="{!item.PM_Service__r.Name}" index="{!index}" fieldNames="[]"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `customLookupHelper` JavaScript code you could filter the `records` result before assigning them to the `listOfSearchRecords` attribute.

Like so:

```js
let listOfSearchRecords = records.filter(
    (el) => el.Department === "Service"
);
component.set("v.listOfSearchRecords", listOfSearchRecords);
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I tried but the code only work "Name". Other fieled (Alias, Username, Division and Department etc..) does not work nothing show. 
when I set Name the code works. Does the filter only work Name? How can I filter other field?
 let listOfSearchRecords = records.filter(
    (el) => el.Name === "John"

Comment: You should make sure that the function querying the data on the back end (the "fetchLookUpValues" method on the Apex class) is querying those fields as well. If it is not querying the Division, for example, then this attribute won't exist in the JavaScript object returned to the front end. Simply make sure the field is queried in the Apex class.

Comment: Hi Renato, Thank you very much! I add the field to Apex so I am success to see the lookup. Thank you!